# WP: Best approach to to link a post to a person

Tags: wordpress

I think this question is common, but I dont find a final solution.

Lets say I have a post type "event", what is the best approach to link a certain post to a certain person (speaker).

at the end i need a list of all speakers (alphabetical, according to their lastname) and of course the information of the speaker in a list of posts and single post view.

The speaker needs 4 data-fields: firstname, lastname, short-bio, weblink.

For a single event the amount of speker could be 1 ore many.

As far as I consider there a three different approaches to do this:

**Custom fields**

All needed custom fields are added directly to the cpt "events" using for example an acf repeater field.

the fields are blank textfields but a jquery ui script is providing an autocompleate feature with all values from the database (all firstnames, lastnames…)
Disadvantages from my perspektive: not so easy to query (especially when i have more than one speaker). The information about one certain speaker needed to give for every events.
Advantage: all information about a certain event, including the information about the speaker are editable on one page in the backend.

**Posttype: "Speaker"**

A second posttype named "speaker" will store all the infos about one speaker. An event could be related to one ore many speakers, for example by using the acf relationship field. 
Disadvantages: all the information about the speaker are to be edit on another page in the backend. The user has first to create a speaker and second link this speaker to an event. 
- question: is it possible, to include a second posttype into the backend of another posttype? For example by providing the possibility to create a new speaker inside the backend of the poststype "events"?
advantages: easy to query, easy to link a event to many speaker

**Custom Taxonomy**

I never tried this but maybe it is a good idea if possible.
The user can choose, add and edit a custom taxonomy providing all the informations (name, firstname, bio etc). 
Is it possible to use more than one field for a custom taxonomy directly in the edit post view?

Maybe there is a final answer for this question?

Comment: maybe this will be a good solution: https://codecanyon.net/item/quick-and-easy-post-creation-for-acf-relationship-fields-pro/17201274

Answer (score 0):

I don't think their is a best approach, it depends on your need and your information architecture.

For example I may  have a archive page of all speakers, so I can list all speakers and I can display the speaker's detail through the url  http://mysite/speaker/ucheng. In this condition, I would prefer the post type solution.

```
Another Solution: Speaker User Role
```

What if you allow the speaker to edit their profile or upload some material for the event? If you want to do this, use default WordPress User and create a speaker role for it, so you can do some access control. Also, I can list the speakers on the frontend, and link the user to the event by using ACF.

For me, I would prefer the user role solution.

Comment: thanks! I agree their is not one best approach, I need something that is easy to use for the user, it would be the best when all information can be edit on one page but i really like the post-type solution.